# Android actionbar always showing overflow menu for menu items in actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem, overflow-menu

Hi I am developing sample Android application in which I am trying to display menu items in actionbar. But my actionbar always showing overflow menu even if there is only single menu item. It is not showing my menu items image in action bar. I have implemented this in following manner

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.samplechromiapp.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/categories"
        android:icon="@drawable/navigation_collapse"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"  
        android:title="Categories"
        android:visible="true"
        />
</menu>
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: set  android:showAsAction="always"

Comment: tried that also but still same result. I am using appcompat.

Comment: try removing xmlns:compat, xmlns:tools, tools:context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code and add extra **xmlns** attribute for your menu and try **app:showAsAction** instead of **android:showAsAction**

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

        <item
            android:id="@+id/categories"
            android:icon="@drawable/navigation_collapse"
            android:title="Categories"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>

 </menu>
```