# Why is my menu always in collapsed state - items pushed in overflow menu

Tags: android

Here is my menu file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".PrepareGroups">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_submit"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_send_now"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/accept"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

My Class signature:

```
public class PrepareGroups extends AppCompatActivity
```

Here is the xml layout of my Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/MyAppbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/color_white"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp">

                    <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
                        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:visibility="invisible"
                        app:indicator="BallScaleMultiple"
                        app:indicator_color="@color/colorAccent" />


                </RelativeLayout>

                <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
                    android:id="@+id/donut_progress"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    app:donut_finished_stroke_width="2dp"
                    app:donut_inner_bottom_text_color="@color/color_white"
                    app:donut_text_color="@color/color_white"
                    app:donut_unfinished_stroke_width="5dp"
                    custom:donut_progress="30" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/MyToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am explicitly defining: `app:showAsAction="always"`

However each time I get the overflow menu with three dots - which I dont want. What do I miss here?

Comment: Can remove android:orderInCategory="100" this line an try.

Comment: I tried that as well - not helping!

Comment: Can u try the accepted answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155963/android-actionbar-always-showing-overflow-menu-for-menu-items-in-actionbar

Comment: Its kind of weird, if I use `android:showAsAction="always"` - works. However I get a red squiggly line under that statement asking me to use `app:showAsAction="always"` instead. for now keep em both.

Comment: oh cool.. Anyway have you checked the xmlns as in the previous link?

Comment: Does not help bro..It gives me the same result.

Comment: If u r still trying to use app:showAsAction try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377305/item-with-appshowasaction-not-showing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

android:showAsAction="ifRoom"

Comment: I think app namespace would be more appropriate here - I get the desired result with android:showAsAction.

Answer (score 0):

Use Toolbar code like this. It may helps you.

```
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/MyToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
```